# how to re-use .env file variables set from build command inside package.json scripts

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I'm using [`env-cmd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) command to set build the .env file. This is what my `build` script looks like:

```json
"build": "env-cmd .env.${REACT_APP_ENV} react-scripts build"
```

After I run the `build` script above I want to run another script that will reuse the variables inside .env file like this.

```
"load:data": "yarn install &&  ./main.js ${REACT_APP_FILE_NAME}"
```

How can I achieve that ? I've been googling for hours but nothing I found so far works.

Comment: Do you have a general `.env` file AND others related to each enviroment? (`.env.development`, `.env.production`)

Comment: I have .env.dev and .env.prod.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command:

```
"load:data": "yarn run build && yarn install &&  ./main.js ${REACT_APP_FILE_NAME}"
```